# Spin down unused Dokku containers (and spin them up upon access)

Tags: docker, dokku

Heroku spins down containers for free accounts when the app isn't accessed for a day. For our system, deployed on Dokku, we have production, staging, as well as developer containers running the same app. Today I noticed a Dokku app hang indefinitely mid-deploy on our dev VM. After investigating, I discovered that the issue was due to insufficient VM memory. After I killed a few containers, the container started successfully. For reference, there are almost 60 containers deployed on our dev box now, but only about 5 of them are being actively used. Often, our devs deploy multiple versions of the same app when testing. Sometimes these apps are no longer needed (in which case we can simply remove them), but more often than not, they'll need to be accessed again a week or two later.

To save resources on our VMs, we would like to spin down dev containers, especially since there are likely to be multiple instances of the same app.

Is this possible with Dokku? If I simply stop containers that haven't been accessed for a while (using `docker stop` command), then the user accessing the app later will be greeted with a 404 page. What I would like to do instead is show the loading icon to the user until the container is spun up again.

Answer (score 1):

simply with dokku commands this is not posible for the moment. maybe you can use ps:stop and try something like if you find a 502 error on nginx, you then try to run a shell script that start the application, but that will of course give the 502 error to the user the first time.